# Sitecore Json rendering & Json variant on page

Tags: json

I have a page that includes a JSON list and I added `sc_device=json` in the URL path and I visit the path it's JSON example `/sitecore/content/item/home?sc_device=json`, when I try to consume it in frontend it will always return HTML, how do I serialize it so I could consume it on frontend as json? My ideas result is a Sitecore page with JSON list variant and consume it on frontend fetch javascript

I implemented it using [this article](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/add-a-json-rendering-and-variant-to-your-page.html)

Comment: I have follow this documentation
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/add-a-json-rendering-and-variant-to-your-page.html

Comment: does it work good on this step? 

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/add-a-json-rendering-and-variant-to-your-page.html#select-a-json-variant_body